Pair trading with strong positive correlation in asset return and cointegration
I am a newbie exploring pairs trading. The main idea is to short-sell the relatively overvalued stocks and buy the relatively undervalued stocks based on the mean-reverting properties of the spread between the asset pair.
However, if the asset pair has strong positive correlation in returns and are also cointegrated, wouldn't pair trading be a bad idea in this case? For instance, when the spread is way below the mean and it is expected to increase back to its mean, it could be that the price of asset A is increasing much faster than the price of asset B, while both asset prices are increasing. In that case, even though the spread between the 2 asset will widen, following the pair trading strategy would cannibalise the profit.
Am i mis-understanding/missing certain criteria about pair trading?

Hi: When a pair is cointegrated, the pair's changes in return are related and the long term relation between the returns also exists. So, if you write the ecm out, given the cointegration relation, you'll have a relation for both. Then, which one you use depends on which one you are trying to profit from. AFAIK, it's the long term equilibrium relation that most people use because this relation is the same one as the regression relationship that's estimated when one tests for cointegration.

Oh, any decent econometrics textbook ( hamilton, hayashi,) will go into all of the details and formulae. Enders is more introductory than the other two but it too will provide all of the details discussed in the first comment.

When I wrote ecm above, I meant "error correction model". I was rushing earlier buit,  If you use the engle-granger framework for cointegration, and you find cointegration exists, then there is always an error correction mode that is equivalent to the original regression model. The ecm is useful because it seperates the short term changes from the long term equilibrium relation. I recommend Water Enders text for the ecm details.

Thanks for the lead @markleeds! I am getting the below ECM model summary:
coef scaled_delta_closing_price_X: 0.99
coef lagged_residual = - 0.81
R2: 0.92
Am i right to say any deviation from the long term equilibrium (coint r/s) in the short term will be reverted at a rate of -81% (coefficient of lagged residual) in the next trading horizon. Hence, even if both assets are in uptrend, the undervalued asset will increase at a faster rate than the fall in prices of the overvalued asset, thereby still leading to an overall profit as long as the long term equilibrium is re-established.

hi pbk: Are you using R because it doesn't look like R output ? I'm not familar with the language you are using so I can't interpret those coefficients ? Even though I probably won't be able to interpret them regardless, you should put the full code that you used to get that output and also put the full output. It's probably best to go back to your question and add it in or start a new question with the exact steps you did to obtain the result. I'm sorry that I can't be more helpful but, with those suggestions, I bet someone will help. Maybe me but I doubt it because I don't use that language.
